# ROS Answers SE migration: Openni_camera

Tags: ros, openni-node, openni-kinect, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I run the openni_camera node and try to see the image through a lan networks i keep seeing  it as pictures not as video. I mean that it is relly slow. I think that maight be because the openni_manager launches a lot of topics.

In my case I don't want most of those topics, I just want the image. Is there any option to launch only the image, or only the parts that I want. For exemple the image and the depth frame?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12187/openni_camera/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OpenNI driver only publishes on topics that have subscribers. You don't pay for what you don't use.

It sounds like your network can't handle all the data, and many image messages are getting dropped. This is common when using wifi. You can test this by running

```
rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_raw
```

on both the computer hooked up to the Kinect and your cross-network machine. The computer hosting the Kinect should see ~30 messages/second, while the other may see less if the network is inadequate.

If bandwidth is the limiting factor, it may help to use compressed versions of the image topics. See if you get better results from

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw theora
```

which will compress the image stream through the Theora codec (note: you must have the `image_transport_plugins` stack installed on both ends). See [image_transport](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport) for details.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3